# Given $M\in\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $\lambda$ eigenvalue of $M$, compare sets based on $M$ for vectors in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $\mathbb{C}^n$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let's say we're given an $n \times n$ real matrix $M$ and that $\lambda$ is a real eigenvalue of $M$. Define two sets as follows:
\begin{align}
X:=\{u\in\mathbb{R}^n : Mu = \lambda u\}\\
Y:=\{u\in\mathbb{C}^n : Mu = \lambda u\}
\end{align}
Prove that $\dim_\mathbb{R}X=\dim_\mathbb{C}Y$

Proof idea/sketch:

Note that for any element $y\in Y$, we can write it as $v+wi$ where $v,w\in X$. So once establish a basis for $X$, say $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ (but I'm still thinking about how to do this properly and consider $M$... ideas?), we can write:
\begin{align}
v=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k \, , \, w=\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k
\end{align}
So for $y\in Y$:
\begin{align}
y&=v+wi\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n a_k x_k + \left(\sum_{k=1}^n b_k x_k\right)i \\
&=\sum_{k=1}^n (a_k + b_k i) x_k
\end{align}
This shows that any $y\in Y$ can be written as a linear combination of $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in X$ and $a_1 + b_1 i,\dots,a_n + b_n i \in\mathbb{C}$.

Then from here, we already know that $\{x_1,\cdots,x_n\}$ are linearly independent because they are a basis for $X$. Need something about spanning/extending to $\mathbb{C}^n$. Then the dimensions have to be equal. Again, this is only a sketch. Any ideas on how to clean this up more? I think the way I'm establishing the basis needs more details and has to consider $M$ somehow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of the matrix $N=M-\lambda I.$ You are computing the nullity of $N.$ The way you do it is by row-reducing $N.$ Notice that the row reduction algorithm will never introduce a complex number, so the row-reduced matrix will **not** depend on the ground field. In particular, its number of zero rows will not depend on the ground field.

Comment: One point I am missing. From what you say X=Y. Hence their dimensions over Real field are equal. But question is dimension of X over Reals equals dimension of Y over Complex field. Are they same??

Comment: $X\neq Y$ One is a complex vector space, another a real vector space, but they ARE of the same dimension.

Comment: Makes sense.  In both cases we have the condition $(M - \lambda I)u = 0$ except $u\in\mathbb{R}^n$ for $X$ and $u\in\mathbb{C}^n$ for $Y$. But $u$ actually doesn't matter because we're only considering $M - \lambda I = 0$ and the LHS only involves reals.